# check multi input char in c

Tags: c, char

```
scanf("%c%c%c%c", &var1, &var2, &var3, &var4);
if ((var1 != 'f' || '+' || '-' || '[' || ']') ||
        (var2 != 'f' || '+' || '-' || '[' || ']') ||
        (var3 != 'f' || '+' || '-' || '[' || ']') ||
        (var4 != 'f' || '+' || '-' || '[' || ']'))
        printf("Invaild input\n");
```

this is my code,i want user to enter 4 variables with space between each one and the output to be invaild if the input is diffrent from any of this chars.right now no matter what i enter into the code the "invalid input" is the output. is there something wrong in here?

Comment: If you want to skip spaces, then you need a space before each `%c`

Comment: That's not how you chain logical expressions together in C. `if (var1 != 'f' && var1 != '+'  && ...`

Comment: Also note -- if you have done any previous input with `scanf` before the call you show, be aware that if you have taken previous character or numeric input you will have a trailing `'\n'` in your input buffer that `"%c"` will happily take as the first character-input. Better to place a leading space before your first `" %c"` as well.

Comment: Note that `x != a || x != b`, having `a != b`, is always true. You want probably `x != a && x != b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why it does not work is because your conditions like `(var1 != 'f' || '+' || '-' || '[' || ']')` do something completely different than you might think. An expression like `(anyBooleanValue || '+')` will always return `true`, regardless what the value of `anyBooleanValue` is. This is because the RHS operand `'+'` is a character literal, i.e. an integral value representing (very likely) the ASCII-code of character '+'. Any integral value other than `0` is treated as `true`, so it reads like `anyBooleanValue || true`, which obviously is always true.

So you actually would have to write something like `if (var1 != 'f' && var1 != '+' && ...` as @WhozCraig mentioned.

But actually you have the same code appearing again and again, and such cases are usually handled by loops. And the test of whether a character appears in a set of possible characters can be solved easily with function `strchr`, which returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character in question or `NULL`, if the character does not occur.  The following code illustrates this:

```
int main() {

#define nvars 4

    char vars[nvars];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        scanf(" %c", &vars[i]);
        if (strchr("f+-[]",vars[i]) == NULL) {  // char not found?
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i<4) {
        printf("Invaild input\n");
    } else {
        printf("valid.\n");
    }
}
```

Note further the leading blank in `scanf(" %c"`, which is for consuming white spaces before the actual character.

Comment: Note: `strchr("f+-[]",vars[i])` will match 1 of 6 `char`: `'f'`,  `'+'`, `'-'`, `'['`, `']'`, `'\0'`.  Usually  users do not or cannot enter a _null character_, so perhaps not of concern for OP.

Answer (score 0):

@Stephan Lechner well identified the problems with OP's code and a good solution.  Below is an alternative solution to check if a character is one of several characters in one step. Use a look-up table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

int mango_test(unsigned char ch) {
  // If char is not too big
#if UCHAR_MAX < 1024
  static const bool good[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = { //
      ['f'] = 1, ['+'] = 1, ['-'] = 1, ['['] = 1, [']'] = 1};  // look-up table
  return good[ch];
#else
  char *s = strchr("f+-[]", ch);
  return s && ch;  // Found in list and not the null character.
#endif
}

int main(void) {
  for (int ch = SCHAR_MIN; ch <= UCHAR_MAX; ch++) {
    int found = mango_test(ch);
    if (found)
      printf("Found %d <%c>\n", ch, ch);
  }
}
```

Output

```
Found 43 <+>
Found 45 <->
Found 91 <[>
Found 93 <]>
Found 102 <f>
```